# NSSet regroup objects by class

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller

So I have this `NSSet` object, straight from a Core Data relationship.
This `NSSet` contains objects that are all subclasses of the same base object (let's call it `RVSuperClass`, itself a subclass of a `NSManagedObject`).

My final objective is to regroup these objects in a UITableView, where each kind of object (`RVSuperClass` subclasses) would make up one section.

Even though there are not many subclasses of `RVSuperClass` (and therefore not many object 'kinds'), there might be a lot of objects in the `NSSet` (hundreds). Therefore, a *for in* loop is not what I'm after.

Is there a way to do this? I'm not very familiar with `NSPredicate` but I guess that would be the best way to do it? Is there a way to beam the results directly in a `NSFetchedResultsController`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `>`there are not many subclasses

That would make it feasible to have the superclass have an attribute that indicates the subclass. Now grouping with fetched results controller's `sectionNameKeyPath` is a breeze.

Comment: Just adding: The (sub)class/entity name of a managed object is not accessible as a property, therefore it cannot be used in a fetch request or sort descriptor. Storing the subclass explicitly in the  superclass is therefore the only option.

Comment: Thanks Mundi and Martin R. I decided to go with another solution even though it's also not very elegant...

Answer (score 0):

Since I have control over what subclasses my RVSuperClass, I decided to go with a relatively awkward solution that doesn't scale well, but it works in this case.

In `viewDidLoad`, for each subclass of `RVSuperClass` I create a predicate:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"self isKindOfClass: %@", [RVSubclassA class]];
```

Using `filteredSetUsingPredicate:` and adding in there a `NSSortDescriptor`, I add the resulting `NSArray` to an ivar `NSMutableArray`, where each `NSArray` will be a section of the tableview.

Too bad I'll have to modify this code (and add yet another `NSPredicate`) if I decide to add a subclass of `RVSuperClass` later on.

Comment: In view of your comment you should still accept the best answer even if you did not implement it.

Comment: Patience my friend. I upvoted your answer for now, but I'll leave a little bit more time for another answer to come up before accepting any as the final answer.